# Historical number of full nodes in Bitcoin

Tags: nodes

Is there anybody keeping historical data regarding the number of full nodes on the Bitcoin network?

There is :
https://getaddr.bitnodes.io/dashboard/?days=90

but it only shows data up to 90 days.

Additional sources also here :

http://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-nodes-need/

Answer (score 4):

There is no measure of the number of full nodes. The number published by many websites is the number of *listening* nodes, instances of software which is advertising itself as available for connections on the Bitcoin network. The term "full" refers to "fully validating", as distinct from non-validating or BIP37 SPV. To be listening you do not need to be validating, or even a Bitcoin node at all (a proxy connection is indistinguishable from a real node).

If you want to know about the number of listening nodes, [bitnodes.io does track numbers for these](https://getaddr.bitnodes.io/dashboard/?days=365) though they appear to be easily manipulated at times (see the spike around September 2015).

Comment: You can check the user agent field ( https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0014.mediawiki ) to see what type of node it its, although there's no gurantee that the node is what it advertises itself to be.

Comment: Why does this data now only go back two years despite records for far longer than that?

Comment: Here is a best effort crawler to get the "accurate" number of bitcoin nodes: https://luke.dashjr.org/programs/bitcoin/files/charts/software.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, LukeJr. But you have to work for it:

"If you want some gigabytes of data, [clone my git repo here](https://gitlab.com/Luke-Jr/my-bitcoin-dnsseed-historical-seeds.txt). It goes back to 2012 June."

[Source.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/5fvsdh/is_anybody_keeping_historical_number_of_full/danhsqc/)

Answer (score 1):

The best source I've found is coin.dance's chart that goes back to 2015:

https://coin.dance/nodes/all